# Horizontal Scroll QTextEdit to specific column number

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qtextedit

I have a `QTextEdit` and given a column number, say `x`, I want to be around to scroll horizontally (by calling `QTextEdit.horizontalScrollBar().setValue()` to a value such that column `x` is the first visible column in the `QTextEdit`. Is there any way to do that?

From what I seen, `QTextEdit.horizontalScrollBar().setValue()` takes a value representing the pixel, not the column number. So simply setting the scroll value to `x` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're suggesting only works for fixed width fonts I think.  So, assuming that's what you have, then you can get the width of the font using QFontMetrics, then just multiply the font width by the column number that you want.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontMetrics
myfont = QFont("courier", 24)
fm = QFontMetrics(myfont)
f_width = fm.width("A")
QTextEdit.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(f_width * x)
```

Comment: Better to use [averageCharWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#averageCharWidth).